# Is the adjoint action of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ on the Schwartz space proper and free?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-actions

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Let $t_1, t_2, t_3$ be generators of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Let us consider a Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}$ defined as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}:= \Bigl\{ \sum_{\alpha=1}^3 F^{(\alpha,j)}t_{\alpha} \text{ }\Bigl \lvert \text{ each } F^{(\alpha,i)} \text{ is a complex-valued Schwartz function for } \alpha=1,2,3 \text{ and } j=1,2, \cdots, n \Big\}
\end{equation}

Next, let $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \SU(2)$ be an arbitrary compactly supported smooth mapping. Then, assuming the adjoint representation of $\SU(2)$ as well as $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, the adjoint action of $\SU(2)$ on $\mathcal{S}$ is defined for any $F \in \mathcal{S}$ by
\begin{equation}
g \cdot F := g F g^{-1} - i [\nabla g]g^{-1}
\end{equation}

Now, my question is that

> Is this adjoint action smooth, closed, proper and free?

Smoohness means this action $(g,F) \to g \cdot F$ is a smooth mapping from $C^\infty_c \bigl(\mathbb{R}^n, \SU(2)\bigr) \times \mathcal{S}$ into $\mathcal{S}$.

Closedness means that the orbit map $\pi : \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}/\SU(2)$ is a closed map.

Proper means that for the mapping $\rho : C^\infty_c \bigl(\mathbb{R}^n, \SU(2) \bigr) \times \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{S}$ defined by $\rho(g,F) := \bigl( g \cdot F, F \bigr)$, we have $\rho^{-1}(K)$ compact whenever $K$ is compact.

Free means that if $g \cdot F =F$ for some $F \in \mathcal{S}$, then $g = e_{\SU(2)}$.

Here are my thoughts:

> If we consider infinite-dimensional notion of smoothness (cf. in the sense of José Luís da Silva), then I think the smoothness requirement should be quite obvious.

> Both $\mathcal{S}$ and $C^\infty_c \bigl(\mathbb{R}^n, \SU(2) \bigr)$ are Montel spaces and therefore have the Heine-Borel property. So, I think there is some hope for closedness and properness requirements.

> I am not quite sure about if this action is free. It requires that $g F g^{-1} - i [\nabla g]g^{-1} =F$ for some $F \in \mathcal{S}$ leads to $g = e_{\SU(2)}$ identically. However, I am not confident about this...

Could anyone please help me?